# Is it possible to test for type exceptions in SmartPy?

Tags: smartpy, testing

How do you catch parameter type exceptions in SmartPy tests?

There's an example of exception testing in: https://smartpy.io/docs/scenarios/testing

*An example from docs*

```
    # Assert exception result
    # catch_exception returns an option:
    #      sp.none if the call succeeds
    #      sp.some(<exception>) if the call fails
    e = sp.catch_exception(c1.state(7), t = sp.TString)
    scenario.verify(e == sp.some("This is false: param > 5"))
```

I can't seem to get it to work with `sp.nat` type errors. I'm not sure what the `t=` value should be, if I'm even using it correctly at all.

```
import smartpy as sp


class Summarise(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(storage=sp.nat(0))

    @sp.entry_point(name='sum')
    def sum(self, x):
        sp.verify((x >= 5) & (x <= 100), "Not in range 5–100")
        with sp.for_("i", sp.range(1, x + 1)) as i:
            self.data.storage += i


@sp.add_test(name="Summarise Test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    contract = Summarise()

    scenario += contract

    # Exception catch attempt
    sp.catch_exception(contract.sum(-1), t=sp.TString)


sp.add_compilation_target("summarise_compiled", Summarise())
```

I want a test to ensure the param type is `nat` and not `int` or anything else. This is why I'd like to explicitly check for the type exception error. To prevent someone from inadvertently changing the type later on. Perhaps there is another approach?

Answer (score 1):

`sp.catch_exception` is used to test when you abort the contract execution with [FAILWITH](https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/#instr-FAILWITH).

`t` is the expected type of the value at the top of the stack when you call `sp.failwith(...)`, `<>.open_some(...)`, etc...

As you could probably notice, SmartPy test interpreter already detects the type inconsistency and gives you a verbose error describing the problem. The call fails on the type-checker, the code doesn't even get executed.

Comment: Ah, now I can see how that works with the example in the docs. 

I would like a test that prevents someone screwing up the param type. So I would like to explicitly check for the type exception error, so that I know the param type is `nat` and not `int`. Is that not possible?

Comment: That should be an end-to-end test. In SmartPy you can add `sp.set_type(x, sp.TNat)` below the entrypoint to enforce the parameter type to be a nat. In typed languages, you can't usually test the type of arguments without reflection.

Comment: +1 to what Rodrigo said - it's good to get into the habit of doing sp.set_type(...) at the top of every entry point - makes the code easier to read/understand and also easier to debug

Comment: @RodrigoQuelhas You can check for the exceptions thrown when incorrect types are provided though. Just wondering if that's possible here. I'll certainly add the set_type snippet thanks for the tip!